# incompatib le types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>

Tags: java, arraylist

How do i convert this ?

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, MTS_DATE_CREATED_STRING);
private Sort(Sort.Direction direction, List<String> properties) {       
}
```

Comment: Step back, think about it. The Sort class wants a LIST of strings. You have a single string. So .... why don't you create a LIST that has that one string inside? And as said, make yourself familiar with the rules and practices of this place, when asking for help with not working code, always provide a [mcve] to us.

Answer (score 0):

As compiler suggest error implies that the Java compiler is unable to resolve a value assigned to a variable or returned by a method, because its type is incompatible with the one declared on the variable or method and it can not convert `String` to a `List<String>` i.e

```
private Sort(Sort.Direction direction, List<String> properties)
```

Into

```
private Sort(Sort.Direction direction, String properties)
```

Comment: Hint: maybe you should focus on the part of "the method expects a list of strings, but too bad, I only have a single string". Maybe maybe maybe there is a super easy way to create a list that contains that string? (but yeah, Sort could offer another constructor that takes a single string and puts that into a list itself)

Comment: @GhostCat Yeap ! dear GhostCat I tried  to explain it with the simplest way imho it was an other constructor. other wise there are many many many ways to resolve it .

Answer (score 0):

The method accepts a List but you are passing a single String.  Wrap that String in a List and it can be passed to the existing method.

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, Arrays.asList(MTS_DATE_CREATED_STRING));
```

The method in question is private, which implies that you may have control over the class in which it resides.  In that case, you may add overloaded versions of the method to accept a single String.

```
private Sort(Sort.Direction direction, String property) { ... }
```

And/or a varargs version that accepts any number of Strings without a collection...

```
private Sort(Sort.Direction direction, String... properties) { ... }
```

Comment: The present days solution is List.of() . Arrays.asList is so java 1.7 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just change from

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, Arrays.asList(MTS_DATE_CREATED_STRING));
```

TO

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, MTS_DATE_CREATED_STRING);
```